# How to create a role in discordjs with permissions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How to create a role in discordjs with permissions?
i have found this code somewhere and i cant find how to create a role with permissions.

````
message.guild.roles.create({ // Creating the role since it doesn't exist.
   data: {
       name: "#Red",
       color: "#ff0000",
       permissions: 0
   }
}).then(role => {
   message.channel.send(`Role \`${role.name}\` created!`);
});```
````

Comment: Here ist the documentation for the ``data`` attribute https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleData. You must provide a valid ``PermissionResolvable``. You may calculate a permission integer here https://discordapi.com/permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
message.guild.roles.create({ // Creating the role since it doesn't exist.
   data: {
       name: "#Red",
       color: "#ff0000",
       permissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR"] //Use , for more. Ex ["KICK_MEMBERS", "BAN_MEMBERS"]
   }
}).then(role => {
   message.channel.send(`Role \`${role.name}\` created!`);
});
```

[Docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#creating-a-role-with-permissions)